# RubyInstaller for Windows issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I'm having issues with the rubyinstaller pack. I deleted the path that the instructions direct me towards and that may be one of the things causing an issue. There is an error message that appears after I type "rails s" which I have downloaded the execjs gem files. However it still repeats the error message after. Please let me know what my code illiterate brain is doing wrong. BTW this is for WINDOWS.

```
C:\Sites>cd railsinstaller_demo

C:\Sites\railsinstaller_demo>rails s
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/run
times.rb:51:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://gi
thub.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUn
available)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/l
ib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/l
ib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-
2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-
2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-
2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-
2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-rails-3
.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-rails-3
.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.4/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.4/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.4/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.4/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.4/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.4/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.4/
lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
        from C:/Sites/railsinstaller_demo/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (requ
ired)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'

    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding "C:\Windows\System32" to my PATH worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need a JavaScript runtime, such as [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/download/). Rails uses this in development mode to compile assets.

Comment: hi, I appreciate the help. thank you. I finally got it to work by adding "C:\Windows\System32" to my PATH which I had previously deleted.

Comment: Also downloading NODEJS. Is there an added benefit of having it besides no more error messages?

Comment: Well asset compilation won't work without a javascript runtime, so something like node is essential. The only other added benefit is if you want to do NodeJS development!